# How to pass multiple button data to 1 query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using multiple buttons generate by php. example:

```
<button onclick="sendData()" id="addRows" data-loc-id="1" data-loc-product="Product1" data-loc-sell="120">Report 1</button>
<button onclick="sendData()" id="addRows" data-loc-id="2" data-loc-product="Product2" data-loc-sell="150">Report 2</button>
```

now i need to pass multiple data in jquery. i am using this code

```
    function sendData() {
    var NewId = $('#addRows').data('loc-id');
    var NewProduct = $('#addRows').data('loc-product');
    var NewSell = $('#addRows').data('loc-sell');
    alert(NewId+" - "+NewProduct+" - "+NewSell);
    }
```

my problem is, it only function for the 1st button, others did not function. i know my code is have problem but how should i write, so that i can have multiple dynamic button but calling/using 1 jquery script and it can receive data from that button.

Ps: if possible i wish to put the jquery into function and save to a js.file anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and i have fixed it.I will give you few tips, that you should follow:

1. Remove the onclick event *savedata()* from the buttons.
2. Bind a click event on classes with name *products* and use *this* to access the properties of the current button that you clicked.
3. The href links and scripts **must** be after *title* tag.

The link is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tyh0Mx7eFgwtNsqdo1l2?p=linter)

Remove the onclick event from the buttons.

```
<button
  class="products"
  data-loc-id="1"
  data-loc-product="Product1"
  data-loc-sell="120"
>
  Report 1
</button>
<button
  class="products"
  data-loc-id="2"
  data-loc-product="Product2"
  data-loc-sell="150"
>
  Report 2
</button>
```

Bind click event on class *.products* and use *this* to access the properties of the button.

```
  $(document).on('click','.products', function(){

          var el = document.getElementsByClassName("products");
          var NewId = $(this).data('loc-id');
          var NewProduct = $(el[NewId - 1]).data('loc-product');
          var NewSell = $(el[NewId - 1]).data('loc-sell');
                /** Just for Check alert */
          alert(NewId+"-"+NewProduct+"-"+NewSell);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. this code is working well. but when i use this code in (add row) function then code showing result undefined ... [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/l84E5Aqmi70S4os2) ... please check and tell me where i am wrong. if you clear this and create a js file so i will complete this project. Thanks For helping

Comment: Use `parseInt` when you want to read integer numbers out of strings

Comment: Thank you @RokoC.Buljan for the tip.But it works anyway.